# Pyspark: Drop/Filter rows based on Summing of columns and Rank

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2020-05-10", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11"],
                   "Slot_Length": [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
                   "Total_Space": [60, 60, 60, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120],
                   "Amount_Over": [-30, -30, -30, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60],
                   "Rank": [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]})

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----+
|      Date|Slot_Length|Total_Space|Amount_Over|Rank|
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----+
|2020-05-10|         30|         60|        -30|   1|
|2020-05-10|         30|         60|        -30|   1|
|2020-05-10|         30|         60|        -30|   2|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   1|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   1|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   1|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   1|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   2|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   2|
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----+
```

For each `Date` I have a `Total_Space` that can be filled. So for `2020-05-10`, I have 60 seconds, and for `2020-05-11` I have 120 seconds.

Each `Date` also already have assigned slots with a certain `Slot_Length`.

For each `Date` I have already calculated the amount of space that `Date` is over in the `Amount_Over` column and have ranked them appropriately based on a priority column not shown here.

What I would like to do is to drop the rows with lowest `Rank` for a `Date` until the `Slot_Length`s add up to the `Total_Space` for a `Date`.

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----+
|      Date|Slot_Length|Total_Space|Amount_Over|Rank|
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----+
|2020-05-10|         30|         60|        -30|   1|
|2020-05-10|         30|         60|        -30|   1|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   1|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   1|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   1|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   1|
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----+
```

In this example, it is as easy as dropping all `Rank` equal to 2, but there will be examples where there is a tie between ranks, so first take the highest ranks, and then take a random one if there is a tie.

What is the best way to do this? I already understand it will need a Window function over the Date to do each calculation over the `Slot_Length`, `Total_Space`, and `Amount_Over` columns correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2020-05-10", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11",
                            "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11"],
                   "Slot_Length": [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
                   "Total_Space": [60, 60, 60, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120],
                   "Amount_Over": [-30, -30, -30, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60],
                   "Rank": [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]})

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
w = Window.partitionBy("Date").orderBy("Rank").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df.withColumn(
    "Cumulative_Sum", F.sum("Slot_Length").over(w)
).filter(
    F.col("Cumulative_Sum") <= F.col("Total_Space")
).orderBy("Date","Rank","Cumulative_Sum").show()
```

which results

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----+--------------+
|      Date|Slot_Length|Total_Space|Amount_Over|Rank|Cumulative_Sum|
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----+--------------+
|2020-05-10|         30|         60|        -30|   1|            30|
|2020-05-10|         30|         60|        -30|   1|            60|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   1|            30|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   1|            60|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   1|            90|
|2020-05-11|         30|        120|        -60|   1|           120|
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----+--------------+
```